# How to remove these curly underlines under my text in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I don't know what I pressed but I am seeing cury underlines under nearly all my text. I thought it must be the spell checker and went to View > Spell Check and disabled it. But it doesn't seem to be the issue. Does any body know what this is and how can I get rid of it?

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the Microsoft TypeScript package installed?

Comment: Yes it looks like I have a package developed by typescriptlang.org. But it wasn't installed anytime recently. These lines started appearing recently. I may have pressed some shortcut keys by mistake that caused this to happen.

Comment: I don't know if there is a reported issue, but for the last couple of weeks people have been seeing this happen with that package installed; it may have updated itself and is misbehaving.